# Parent Activity always destroyed on start of childe activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have a problem which is really boggling me. The parent activity in the an I'm developing is always destroyed as soon as any of children is launched. This makes use of the back button cause the application to lag as the parent activity has to be created again.
Heres Android manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dev.dita.daystarmemo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.dev.dita.daystarmemo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.dev.dita.daystarmemo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MemoApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_memo_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="e76f495714db69684d45e3cb181116b8c21b649e" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.welcome.WelcomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.profile.ProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.dev.dita.daystarmemo.ui.main.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.memos.MemosChatActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_memos_chat"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.memos.MemoGroupActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.dev.dita.daystarmemo.ui.memos.MemoGroupActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.memos.NewMemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_new_memo"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.connections.ConnectionsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_connections"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.dev.dita.daystarmemo.ui.main.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.connections.NewConnectionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_new_connection"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.connections.ConnectionsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.dev.dita.daystarmemo.ui.connections.ConnectionsActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.connections.ConnectionDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_connection_details"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.connections.ConnectionsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.dev.dita.daystarmemo.ui.connections.ConnectionsActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.settings.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.main.MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.dev.dita.daystarmemo.ui.main.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".receivers.NotificationRemovedReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.dev.dita.daystarmemo.BROADCAST_NOTIFICATION_REMOVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".receivers.PushReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="0">
                <action android:name="com.dev.dita.daystarmemo.BROADCAST_NOTIFICATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.dev.dita.daystarmemo" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".services.GcmService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".services.MemoService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name=".services.PushReceiverIntentService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name=".services.PushIntentService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name=".services.MemoPendingDownloadService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name=".services.ConnectionService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name=".services.RegistrationService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.documents.DocumentsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_documents"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.dev.dita.daystarmemo.ui.main.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".services.TransfersService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.memos.MemoGroupActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_memo_group"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.dev.dita.daystarmemo.ui.main.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ui.SearchableActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.schedule.ScheduleActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_schedule"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.dev.dita.daystarmemo.ui.main.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".services.ScheduleService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My back button implementation is similar that of the Google IO 2015 app. I don't use any flags when starting any activity so i don't thinks that's the issue.

This is how I launch the activities:

```
private void goToNavDrawerItem(int item) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (item) {
            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_HOME:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                break;
            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_MEMOS:
                intent = new Intent(this, MemoGroupActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("section", MemoGroupActivity.MEMO);
                createBackStack(intent);
                break;
            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_GROUPS:
                intent = new Intent(this, MemoGroupActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("section", MemoGroupActivity.GROUP);
                createBackStack(intent);
                break;
            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_CONNECTIONS:
                createBackStack(new Intent(this, ConnectionsActivity.class));
                break;
            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_SCHEDULE:
                createBackStack(new Intent(this, ScheduleActivity.class));
                break;
            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_DOCUMENTS:
                createBackStack(new Intent(this, DocumentsActivity.class));
                break;
            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_SETTINGS:
                createBackStack(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
                break;
            case NAVDRAWER_ITEM_LOGOUT:
                showLogoutDialog();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Heres the create back stack method

```
private void createBackStack(Intent intent) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            TaskStackBuilder builder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            builder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);
            builder.startActivities();
        } else {
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have checked the "Don't keep activities" option under Settings>Developer options.
If it is checked, then all the activities will be destroyed when launching new ones.

Comment: Ok, I think you should post how you are launching the activities and also the code of the onOptionsItemSelected method. Maybe there is an error there.
Have you already checked the documentation?https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

There is also a sample app there.

Comment: I saw that you added the code for createBackStack and noticed that on < Jelly Bean you are calling finish(), that will destroy the parent activity, are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: That snippet was from  the google io app. i'm still researching about that. But i'm running kitkat and lollipop but the parent activity is being destroyed. Could it be the taskbuilder??

Comment: It could be. I'm not sure what you are using the taskbuilder for. Why don't you just start the activity using startActivity(intent)?

Comment: Just tried it. back button doesn't work i'm actually left with a white screen when i press the back button

Comment: It seems Taskbuilder destroys parent. I guess i have to find a way to add parent to stack without destroying parent